# Equivalent of PHP's dirname(__FILE__) in Ruby?

Tags: php, ruby, programming-languages

What is the equivalent of PHP's `dirname(__FILE__)` in Ruby ?

Comment: have you tried http://www.phptoruby.com/submit-code ?

Comment: great site ! but I could not find dirname(__FILE__) over there

Comment: if you're using PHP 5.3, there's also `__DIR__` so you don't need the `dirname()` function call -- see http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: no, but you can submit your inquiries to. Just another resource!

Comment: @Spudley Nice tip, but not terribly relevant to the question. :)

Comment: @Mile Fuzz - that's why it's a comment rather than an answer :)

Answer (score 4):

With the help from @potac and @jakub-hampl I arrived at

```
File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))
```

This gave me exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

```
puts File.expand_path(__FILE__)
```

I'm not familiar with Ruby (but with PHP) and I found this in [Rails for PHP Developers](http://amzn.to/f1hb8A)

Comment: that return the path to the file not the folder it is present in.
Thanks though, it helped me get to this.
File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)) . 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
File.dirname __FILE__
```

Comment: helps, but only with __FILE__ return the complete path to file

Comment: @JimRubenstein it's Ruby, parentheses are not required. (And depending on your styleguide, they might be prohibited in some situations).

Comment: Sorry for being a jerk and -1ing, it just so happened that I had just finished a tirade about how I hate the fact that Ruby allows parens to be optional. I understand the expressive-ness in some situations, but it really adds a ton of confusion to the code. The difference between an object property and an object method becomes ambiguous. I'll +1 because i found use in the answer, i just wish that you'd used parens instead of promoting the language "feature" in this case

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Ruby 2.0, Ruby also has a [`__dir__` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__) that implements what you're asking for directly.

Answer (score 0):

`Dir.pwd` is the equivalent of PHP's `dirname(__FILE__)`

http://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-pwd

Comment: Actually, no. This returns the current working directory of the process, not the file it was called.